# How can I join with the output of a query (as if it were a table) into a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, rdbms

I am not so into SQL and I have the following problem. I am working with **MySql**

I have to change this query:

```
SELECT 
        USR.id                              AS hq_user_id,
        USR.local_user_id,       
        LCZ.id                              AS localization_id,  
        LCZ.description                     AS description,
        LCZ_COUNTRY_LEVEL.id                                AS country_id,
        LCZ_COUNTRY_LEVEL.description                AS country_description
FROM Localization AS LCZ

INNER JOIN User AS USR
    ON USR.localization_id = LCZ.id

INNER JOIN Localization AS LCZ_COUNTRY_LEVEL
    ON LCZ_COUNTRY_LEVEL.country_id = LCZ.country_id

WHERE USR.local_user_id = 999
```

removing this second inner join:

```
INNER JOIN Localization AS LCZ_COUNTRY_LEVEL
    ON LCZ_COUNTRY_LEVEL.country_id = LCZ.country_id
```

and replacing it with the output of this other query that I wrote:

```
SELECT
    LCZ2.id                 AS localization_id_nation_level,
    LCZ2.country_id         AS country_id
FROM Localization AS LCZ2
WHERE
     LCZ2.region_id is null
AND  LCZ2.province_id is null
AND  LCZ2.city_id is null
AND  LCZ2.district_id is null
AND  LCZ2.town_id is null
AND  LCZ2.village_id is null
```

The join condition should be:

**LCZ.country_id** should be the same of the **LCZ2.country_id         AS country_id** field returned in the second query.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of joining to the `Localization` table, join to your desired *subquery*.  Not much magic here.  Just wrap the subquery in parentheses, give it an alias (I used `t` below), and then use that alias in the join condition.

```
SELECT 
    USR.id AS hq_user_id,
    USR.local_user_id,       
    LCZ.id AS localization_id,  
    LCZ.description,
    LCZ_COUNTRY_LEVEL.id AS country_id,
    LCZ_COUNTRY_LEVEL.description AS country_description
FROM Localization AS LCZ
INNER JOIN User AS USR
    ON USR.localization_id = LCZ.id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT country_id
    FROM Localization AS LCZ2
    WHERE
        region_id IS NULL AND
        province_id IS NULL AND
        city_id IS NULL AND
        district_id IS NULL AND
        town_id IS NULL AND
        village_id IS NULL
) t
    ON LCZ.country_id = t.country_id
WHERE USR.local_user_id = 999;
```